# Many to Many relationship in Hibernate - Designing object model

Tags: java, hibernate, object-model

I have a strange problem of having the correct object model for many-to-many relationship. Say, I have 3 entities: CLASS, SUBJECT, STUDENT with below data model:

```
Table CLASS:
ID INTEGER,
CLASSNAME VARCHAR

Table SUBJECT:
==============
ID INTEGER
NAME VARCHAR

Table STUDENT:
==============
ID INTEGER
PRIMARY_SUBJECT INTEGER REFERENCES SUBJECT (ID)
CLASS_ID INTEGER REFERENCES CLASS (ID)

Table CLASS_SUBJECTS (Subjects that are taught in a class, a subject can be taught in more than one class):
===========================================================================
CLASS_ID INTEGER REFERENCES CLASS(ID)
SUBJECT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES SUBJECT(ID)
```

How do I ensure that the CLASS and PRIMARY_SUBJECT of a STUDENT are valid entries? A pair of CLASS and PRIMARY_SUBJECT are valid only if there is an entry in CLASS_SUBJECTS table.

I want the object model to contain both the CLASS and PRIMARY_SUBJECT, something like this:

```
Class STUDENT {
 .... //Some fields
 CLASS myClass;
 SUBJECT primarySubject;
}
```

PS: I don't want to replace CLASS & SUBJECT members with CLASS_SUBJECT, as there are many more things in CLASS member that are needed as part of STUDENT object.

Comment: It is a long shot. Is this correct if you change your Table Student to Table STUDENT:
==============
ID INTEGER
PRIMARY_SUBJECT INTEGER REFERENCES CLASS_SUBJECTS(SUBJECT_ID )
CLASS_ID INTEGER REFERENCES CLASS_SUBJECTS (SUBJECT_ID )

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond, but I don't want to change the data model. I am more interested in knowing if I can somehow force the constraints in object model using Hibernate.